# soffice --headless: Update .odt TOC from command line

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

`soffice --headless` is a powerful tool. With this command you can import and export files from several formats, etc.

My issue: I have a `.odt` document and **I would like to refresh [TOC (Table of Contents)](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/TOC#Overall_Description)'s document from command line** (*1), something like:

```
soffice --headless --invisible --update_all_TOC's: my_file.odt
```

I have digging into soffice help ( `soffice --headless --help` ) but I don't found this command :)

(*1) Notice: be aware! We are talking about to refresh from command line, without open GUI.